# Передать несколько значений в параметр report builder

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

Как программно передать в параметр отчета несколько значений? Я передаю так :

```
    ReportParameter id_shift = new ReportParameter("id_sectionshift", string.Join(", ", GlobalVariable.arrIdShift));
    reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { id_shift });
    this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

После этого в отчете вижу это :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если исправлю вручную вот так, то все работает :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал меня "," на ";" не помогает. Пробовал делать сноску "\n", тоже не помогает. По колесу стучал, капотом хлопал - метод тыка не затащил, прошу помощи.

Comment: а так `string.Join("\r\n", GlobalVariable.arrIdShift)`?

Comment: @Ruslan_K тоже самое :(((

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось необходимо использовать другой конструктор [ReportParametr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms251764.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Заработало когда сделал так :

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter ( "id_sectionshift", GlobalVariable.arrIdShift));
```

Где `GlobalVariable.arrIdShift` массив строк.

Ответ получил [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/ebfb95a4-60f2-4818-9a4a-2aa6033cc5f8/-report-builder?forum=fordesktopru).